# Applying eval function to numpy array

Tags: numpy

My data file is column separated,

```
0   0   0   0.00   0.00   0.00   x1  y1  z1
0   0   0   0.75   0.75   0.00   -x1  -y1  z1
```

and and I want to read this file and do some column operation using numpy array. Here, x1,y1,z1 are variables defined in program. So my code is

```
import numpy as np
x1,y1,z1=0.5,0.5,0.5
data=np.genfromtxt("./inputfile",dtype=str)
coordinate=data[:,0]+data[:,6]
```

But error occurs,

```
File "/home/hermite/Codes/spinel.py", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I understand why this error occurs, because for string data type, + operation is not allowed. So I have to change the data array to number.
I tried eval() function, but this does not apply to numpy array.. So my question is, how do I apply eval() function to numpy array?

Comment: What does `data` look like if you specify `dtype=None`?

Comment: If I excuete `print data` and `print data.dtype.type`, then it shows `(0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'x1', 'y1', 'z1')` and `<type 'numpy.void'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sequence of operations that will turn your sample text into a 2d numpy array, filling in values for x1,y1,z1 in the process.  These are lines from an ipython session.

Simulate reading from a file by cut and pasting text

```
In [109]: txt=b"""0   0   0   0.00   0.00   0.00   x1  y1  z1
0   0   0   0.75   0.75   0.00   -x1  -y1  z1"""    
In [110]: txt=txt.splitlines()
```

let `genfromtxt` assign dtypes for each column.  The result is a structured array with a mix of int, float, and string columns (or fields):

```
In [111]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None)    
In [112]: data
Out[112]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, b'x1', b'y1', b'z1'),
       (0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.0, b'-x1', b'-y1', b'z1')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', 'S3'), ('f7', 'S3'), ('f8', 'S2')])
```

Your `coordinate` could then be calculated with:

```
In [137]: coordinate=data['f0']+[eval(a) for a in data['f6']]
# array([ 0.5, -0.5])
```

I am accessing fields by their fieldname, and converting the string values one by one with `eval`.

To transform the whole array to a 2d numeric array, make an empty array to hold the transformed data

```
In [113]: data1=np.zeros((2,9),float)
```

Fill in the numeric columns with a simple copy:

```
In [114]: for i in range(6):
    data1[:,i]=data[data.dtype.names[i]]
   .....:     
 # or `data1[:,:6]=data[list(data.dtype.names[:6])].tolist()`
```

For the string columns, pass the values individually through `eval`:

```
In [115]: x1,y1,z1=.25,.5,.75    
In [116]: for i in range(6,9):
    data1[:,i]=[eval(a) for a in data[data.dtype.names[i]]]
   .....:
```

The resulting data:

```
In [117]: data1
Out[117]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.75,  0.75,  0.  , -0.25, -0.5 ,  0.75]])
```

`eval(a)` could be replaced by a more secure function, for example one that only interprets acceptable strings like `x1`.

Comment: thanks. but why do you wrap eval function with [ ] in `In [137]: coordinate=data['f0']+[eval(a) for a in data['f6']]` ? I just tried omitting [ ] and excuting `eval(a) for a in data['f6']` but erros occurs. Wrapping it with [ ] , so `[eval(a) for a in data['f6']]` does not make error. What's the reason?

Comment: `[eval(a) for a in ...]` is a list comprehension, a kind of Python loop or mapping.  It calcs `eval(a)` for each element of `data[]`, and returns the results as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`data[:, 0].astype(np.double)`

FYI generally it is not a good idea to leave strings in memory like this.  Consider at least using numpy struct arrays and potentially just using the coefficients for your x y z columns so you can store them as integers/doubles in memory.

Comment: This handles the 1st 6 columns that can be parsed as floats, but not the 3 symbolic columns.

Comment: It handles symbolic just fine if you can encode a fixed polynomial as just coefficients in the spreadsheet.  Eval will be very slow and usually people complain about security when pulling from a file - not that that should stop you.

Comment: Do you mean, instead of putting `-x1 y1 -z1` in the file, you put `-1 1 -1`?

Comment: Maybe he's using `-x1` for human readability.  `eval` could be replaced with a more secure function.

Comment: Yep,  but for the human readability it doesn't have much benefit over the other columns if the variables are always the same... and if you factor in the trouble of true symbolic evaluation, it seems to not be justified if it's a fixed polynomial he's working with.  eval will still be slow and a weapon wielded with much care.

Comment: yes.with `x1=1`,  `x1` means `1` and `-x1` for `-1`. That is written in that way because it's somemathematical oepration